# Adding a Div <> into a php while loop function

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a select query in php. Everything is working except for the Time function in which i would like to add a div function to call my countdown timer in it and to use the value time from the database. Does anyone have any suggestion on how i can include my countdown timer into a php script ?

Cheers

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo
   "".$row{'Url'}."<br>"; 
   echo 
   "Name:".$row{'Name'}."<br>";
   echo
   "Price: $ ".$row{'Price'}."<br>";
   echo
   "Time:" <div class = "qwerty"  data-countdown= .$row{'Time'}.></div>"<br>";
   echo
   "Location:".$row{'Location'}."<br>";
   echo
   "Description:".$row{'Description'}."<br>";
   echo ("-----------------------")."<br><br>";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change this:

```
echo
   "Time:" <div class = "qwerty"  data-countdown= .$row{'Time'}.></div>"<br>";
```

to this:

```
echo
   'Time: <div class = "qwerty"  data-countdown= '.$row{'Time'}.'></div><br>';
```

Comment: Works like a charm - Will accept the answer once the system allows me to do so :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use backslash in your code like this:

```
echo   "Time: <div class = \"qwerty\"  data-countdown= ".$row{'Time'}."></div><br>";
```

It is usefull if you want to use tables also for example:

```
echo  "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\"><tr><td>sdfgdfg</td><tr></table>";
```

Comment: or he can just use single quotes `'`

Comment: Yes, there is more than one solution, and you was the fastest :-)